# THREEjs "Random" rotation leading to specific face pointing in a certain direction

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, simulation, dice

I'm trying to create a dice roller using THREEjs. Using a physics simulation is well above my current skills so instead...

If I have a mesh of an arbitrary shape (cube for now), I want to pick a random face and rotate the cube so that face faces the camera. I can already do this with quartenions, but I need to add more "flare", the cube should spin (in more directions than just x or just y) slow down and then go to that face.

Below is my current code, if I just add on a rotation to the selected face at the end it will look unnatural because the direction might change abrubtly.

```
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material_1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00FF00,  map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("1.png"), transparent: true });
// create other materials and make array

class Die {
  constructor(scene) {
    console.log(this);
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, matArray);
    console.log(this.mesh);
    this.mesh.material.opacity = 0.1;
    this.mesh.material.transparent = true;
    this.rotationSpeed = 0.015;
    scene.add(this.mesh);

  }

  getMutablePosition = () => this.mesh.position;

  getMutableRotation = () => this.mesh.rotation;

  tick = () => this.updateRotation();

  updateRotation() {
    // console.log(this.mesh.geometry.faces);
    this.mesh.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true; 
    this.mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true; 
    const rotation = this.mesh.rotation;
    if (this.rotationSpeed > 0.01) {
      rotation.x += this.rotationSpeed;
      rotation.y += this.rotationSpeed;
      this.rotationSpeed -= 0.005 * Math.random();
    } else if (rotation.x % (2 * Math.PI) > 0.04) {
      rotation.x += this.rotationSpeed;
      rotation.y += this.rotationSpeed;
      this.rotationSpeed += 0.0005 * Math.random();
    }
  }
}

export default Die;
```

Edit: So to clarify, I want to give the cube (and later more complicated shapes) a face and have multiple revolutions slow down and stop on that face. However if say it only needs to rotate along the x axis to get to its target, there should be some spins in y so it doesnt look strange,.

Comment: So you're looking to smoothly decelerate the cube's rotation?

Comment: Yes but in a way that starts of looking random and then stopping at a particular face. What I have already works for smooth deceleration but only works for angle_x = angle_y. If I treat x and y separately it sometimes looks really strange because it will stop rolling in x and then roll across multiple faces in y